# MySQL - Aliasing the database name?

Tags: mysql, alias

I have a systematic problem that I don't have the time or budget to fix and I was hoping that there was a mysql hack I could deploy which would save my little world from impending doom.

The creators of the system I now administrate didn't realise that a database name could contain characters other than letters, numbers and underscores. As a result queries look like this.

```
SELECT * FROM {$db}.settings
```

If the database name contains something non-standard... like a dash. The world ends and all queries break.

The db prefix is there because this system used-to-but-doesn't-now run a multi-site feature.

You would think that I could fix this with..

```
$db = "`{$db}`";
```

If only.. you see it turns out a load of javascript functionality sends around this database name to keep track of which site to update. By adding these quotes, you break all of that as instead of getting `databasename`, it is getting

```
`databasename`
```

So... why don't I just set the database name to something that is compatible.. this system ships to external servers where I have no control over the database name...

The pain...

Is there a way to alias the database name in a preliminary query which will then affect all subsequent queries. Basically set a constant?

Something like that would then work on all subsequent queries. Something like:

```
set `$db` AS database
```

I can just set the $db variable to database and it should run.. if this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would fix the queries using something like:

```
sed -e "s/{\$db}/\`{\$db}\`/g" -i * */* */*/* */*/*/*
```

with a big **warning** to test this first, because this may mess up a lot. Especially check if your `sed`'s `-i` option needs a suffix or not.

Answer (score 1):

If you operate always on one database ($db doesn't change after you connect to the database), then just after connecting issue

```
USE `$db`;
```

and remove `{$db}.` prefix from all queries. `USE` query sets the active (default) database for future queries in current connection.

You didn't tell what programming language you are using, so I will assume PHP. Usually you can set default database while establishing connection ([`mysqli_connect()`, `$dbname` parameter](http://.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect.php)). Also, there may be a function like [`mysqli_select_db()`](http://php.net/mysqli_select_db) that you can call after you connect.